# Cannot invoke 'taskCreated' with an argument list of type '([String : String?])'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I finished building a task iOS app using Swift. The whole app was completed and finished with no errors and was functioning correctly. I was using Xcode 6 but I upgraded to the latest Xcode Beta not long ago which is Xcode 7 Beta. In one of my swift files, since some of the logic has been altered from switching xcode 6 to xcode 7 beta, there is only one error that was once not an error from xcode 6. In my of my lines the error was; "Cannot invoke 'taskCreated' with an argument list of type '([String : String?])'" How do I get around this error?

The line of code is below:

```
delegate!.taskCreated(["name": nameTask, "description": descriptionTask])
```

If anyone wants to see my "taskCreated" function, I'll post it below here as well.

```
func taskCreated(task: Dictionary<String, String>) {
    print("in task created delegate of ViewController")
    print(task)

    dataSource[0].append(task)


    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: try like this delegate!.taskCreated(["name": nameTask, "description": descriptionTask!])

Answer (score 0):

One of `nameTask` or `descriptionTask` is of type `String?`. You can unwrap them with an exclamation mark:

```
delegate!.taskCreated(["name": nameTask!, "description": descriptionTask!])
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `nameTask` or `descriptionTask` is not a String but an `Optional(String)` (represented as `String?`) which is why it says you cannot call `taskCreated` with `[String: String?]`. You can only send `[String: String]`.

If you're sure `nameTask` and `descriptionTask` are never nil, just replace its call with:
`delegate!.taskCreated(["name": nameTask!, "description": descriptionTask!])`